# combine mutate(across) and case_when to fill multiple columns with 0 depending on condition

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when, across

In a dplyr workflow I try to paste a 0 in each column of a dataframe after the newvar column when newvar == 0, else do nothing.
I modified the iris dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 150 # sample size

iris1 <- iris %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(), .before = Sepal.Length) %>% 
    mutate(newvar = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n), .before = Sepal.Length ) %>% 
    mutate(across(.[,3:ncol(.)], ~ case_when(newvar==0 ~ 0)))
```

I tried a solution like here [How to combine the across () function with mutate () and case_when () to mutate values in multiple columns according to a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668137/how-to-combine-the-across-function-with-mutate-and-case-when-to-mutate).
My understanding:

1. with `.[,3:ncol(.)]` I go through the columns after newvar column.
2. with `case_when(newvar==0` I try to set the condition.
3. with `~ 0` after `newvar==0` I try to say paste 0 if condition is fulfilled.

I know that I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what! Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need to do `.[,3:ncol(.)]`. `3:ncol(.)` works just fine.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! Now how can I leave the other rows of `3:ncol(.)` with their original value. Now these cells get a NA. So the question is: If newrow==1 change nothing in `3:coll(.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.[,3:ncol(.)]` are the values of the column and not the actual column numbers. Using `3:ncol(.)` should work fine.

In general, it is also better to avoid referring column by positions and instead use their names. You can do this in one `mutate` call.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 150

iris %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), 
        newvar = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n), 
        across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, ~ case_when(newvar==0 ~ 0, 
                                                     newvar == 1 ~ .)))
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you again Ronak. Maybe you can help with the above comment of mine:How can I leave the other rows of 3:ncol(.) with their original value. Now these cells get a NA. So the question is: If newrow==1 change nothing in 3:coll(.)