# R across find only positive or only negative values tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, across

In dplyr [Column-wise operations](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html) has this example:

```
df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b"), y = c(1, 1), z = c(-1, 1))
# Find all rows where EVERY numeric variable is greater than zero
df %>% filter(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x > 0))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   x         y     z
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 b         1     1
```

if we change a bit the tibble:

```
df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c(1, 1, -1), z = c(-1, 1, -1))
```

and we want to get negative or positive values for both columns we need to name the columns:

```
df %>% filter((y > 0 & z > 0) | (y < 0 & z < 0))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>  x         y     z
#>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 b         1     1
#> 2 c        -1    -1
```

with `across()` how can this be done?

```
df %>% filter(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x > 0 | .x < 0))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>  x         y     z
#>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1    -1
#> 2 b         1     1
#> 3 c        -1    -1
```

Comment: Very good problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to check for either all `TRUE` or all `FALSE` from a set of conditionals like `c(T, T)`, `c(T, F)` and `c(F, F)`. Now -

- `if_all` will filter `c(T, T)`
- `!if_any` will filter again `c(T, T)` from `!` i.e. negation of remaining values
- these two will be joined by a `|` i.e. *OR*
- Thus, we will have only `c(T, T)` & `c(F, F)`

Thus, this will do

```
df %>% filter(if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ .x > 0) | !if_any(where(is.numeric), ~ .x < 0))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 b         1     1
2 c        -1    -1
```

Alternative

```
df %>% filter(if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ .x > 0) | across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x < 0))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 b         1     1
2 c        -1    -1
```

Let's check on bigger example

```
set.seed(201)
df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10], x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), z = -1*rnorm(10))

> df
   A           x           y           z
1  A  0.28606069  0.69329617  0.24400084
2  B -0.34454603  0.22380936  0.98825314
3  C  0.32576373  0.39845694 -1.24206048
4  D -1.69658097  1.01347438  1.68266603
5  E -1.28548252 -0.64785307 -1.44289063
6  F -0.07503189  0.64845271  0.46543975
7  G  0.26693735  0.20734270 -0.69366150
8  H  0.05593404  0.06439014  0.08772557
9  I -2.30403431  0.66938092  0.95508038
10 J  0.18900414 -0.37425445 -0.17010088

> df %>% filter(if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ .x > 0) | !if_any(where(is.numeric), ~ .x < 0))
  A           x           y           z
1 A  0.28606069  0.69329617  0.24400084
2 E -1.28548252 -0.64785307 -1.44289063
3 H  0.05593404  0.06439014  0.08772557
```

Comment: Great solution my friend. I was trying to figure out a way to do it with one `across` function. So far I failed.

Comment: :) I was involved in this problem for hours.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't yield the required output!

Comment: which one?  `across` doesn't work like `if`, `at`, `all` etc.  See package vignette for explanation

Comment: No I mean why we just can't use one `if_all` with two conditions. In which case you don't add across to check for the second condition.

Comment: because we are checking for mutual contradictory conditions simultaneously.  like we have to filter same values from `c(T, T)`, `c(T, F)` and `c(F, F)`.  Let me add an explanation in answer.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Thank you for letting me know. Look forward to our future discussion about other methods and problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think since you are dealing with 2 variables in a row-wise operation, it would be much easier to use `map2` from `purrr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c(1, 1, -1), z = c(-1, 1, -1))

df %>%
  filter(map2_lgl(y, z, ~ (.x > 0 & .y > 0) | (.x < 0 & .y < 0)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 b         1     1
2 c        -1    -1
```

Comment: Thus there’s not yet a way to do with across yet. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: No there is, check out my dear friend @AnilGoyal's version and I'm working on it too.

Comment: Just bear in mind that you can easily use `purrr` functions for row-wise operations.

Comment: This won't work if there are more than two variables

Comment: Yes in that case we have to use `pmap` .

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you for the edit. I had added an extra unnecessary step.